# Problems to make webapp with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, maven

Actually, i am making a webproject with maven in command line.

mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 -DgroupOd=ar.com -DartifactId=RETOP

then i write  mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:eclipse
1) in the project when I import I do not see the folder src / main / java why not?

2) the eclipse not take me M2_REPO variable (in another workspace it works) I have added the variable and the jar.

3) Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet. PropiedadesArg      Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)

thanks

Comment: Removed Spanish Text: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2) the eclipse not take me M2_REPO
>   variable (in another workspace it
>   works) I have added the variable and
>   the jar.

For every workspace, you need to call [`mvn eclipse:configure-workspace`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/configure-workspace-mojo.html) once. This initializes the `M2_REPO` variable.

> 3) Description Resource Path Location
>   Type Java compiler level does not
>   match the version of the installed
>   Java project facet. PropiedadesArg
>   Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java
>   Version Mismatch)

The compiler level is taken from the pom configuration of the maven compiler plugin.

**Example (for 1.6 compliance):**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

But apart from that: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` shouldn't be used any more, [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) is the way to go for Eclipse + Maven. It uses an embedded Maven installation to actually run the maven build (or parts of it) in Eclipse, whereas the Maven Eclipse Plugin just configures Eclipse from the outside. Here's a [thread were the Maven founders discuss this topic](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Preparing-for-M2Eclipse-1-0-amp-no-support-for-the-maven-eclipse-plugin-td139921.html).

---

Also:

```
mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.0
-DgroupOd=ar.com -DartifactId=RETOP
  ^^^^^^^
```

here's a typo, it's `groupId`, not `groupOd`

---

Oh, now I get it. `eclipse:eclipse` uses the variable `MAVEN_REPO`, not `M2_REPO` (`M2_REPO` is created and maintained by m2eclipse). Anyway, in Eclipse, select `Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables`, add or edit the `M2_REPO` variable and set it to `<path to your home directory>/.m2/repository`, e.g. `C://users/yournamehere/.m2/repository`

Comment: i I did everything and continue to have the same problems.
what could it be?

Comment: i know, but i continues have the same problems with m2_repo

Comment: i Solved this, i only see a warning